# transforming variables to use for prediction in regression model

Tags: r, regression, data-analysis, prediction

I have the following dataset, I wish to find the best varibles among `pred1`, `pred2`, `pred3`, `pred5`, and `pred6` to buid a regression model to predict `resp1` and `resp2`.

So far, I only find out `pred2` seems like the one to use for `resp1`.

```
library(ggplot2)

testdat <- read.csv("testdat.csv", header = T)

plot(testdat$pred2,testdat$resp1)
m1<-lm(resp1~pred2, data=testdat)
smooth <- smooth.spline(testdat$pred2,testdat$resp1, spar=1)
lines(smooth, col='red', lwd = 2, lty = 2)
```

[image]

I tried `^2`,`sqrt`,`log` to do the transformations, when I check `summary(m1)`, no matter what I tried, the `R-squared` seems no higher than `53%`, desperate.

The same about transforming variables to predict `resp2`, no higher than 66%

```
plot(testdat$pred3,testdat$resp2)

m1<-lm(resp2~pred3, data=testdat)
smooth <- smooth.spline(testdat$pred3,testdat$resp2, spar=1)
lines(smooth, col='red', lwd = 2, lty = 2)
```

[image]

**Sample dataset:
https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/846977/testdat.csv**

Having more than one variable is highly considered, if you are trying to generate a regression model to predict `resp1` and then `resp2` by using one or more varibles among  `pred1`, `pred2`, `pred3`, `pred5`, and `pred6`. What would you do?

Comment: What is your question? Do you have a reason to think R-squared should be higher than 0.53? Are you limiting yourself to linear regression on a single variable? Since you're plotting splines, are you interested in a spline-based model?

Comment: I just try to find the best variables to predict ```resp1``` and ```resp2```. I hope to use regression model.@Gregor-reinstateMonica

Comment: I still don't understand what you need help with. Do you consider spline regression? Or do you want to stick with linear regression? What about having more than one variable in the model?  Do you only care about R^2? Or do you worry about over-fitting, and want to perhaps use a test set to make sure your model is general? There are many textbooks on fitting models... what do you hope to have here, a tutorial or summary of a textbook? That's not really what this site is for...

Comment: Having more than one variable is highly considered, if you are trying to generate a regression model to predict ```resp1``` and then ```resp2``` by using one or more varibles among  ```pred1```, ```pred2```, ```pred3```, ```pred5```, and ```pred6```. What would you do? @Gregor-reinstateMonica

Comment: Would you say you are looking for variable selection methods? I would use LASSO or glmnet to pick variables, see the `glmnet` package. With the second picture you show, it's clearly nonlinear so I might use a GAM from the mgcv package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use linear regression, you could perform a RESET test on your data and work from there:

```
resettest(resp1~pred2, data=testdat, power = 2:3, type = "regressor)
```

If the p.value is lower than 0.05, then you have to change the model.
And use adjusted R2 instead of R2 to make comparisons between models.

Otherwise, more information regarding your data might be necessary (e.g. what is its nature?)